# How to set up GIT in a new computer with the same ssh keys used in the server to connect

Tags: git, virtual-machine, mobaxterm

I have a VM with ubuntu that I have installed GIT and is set up correctly to connect automatically to the GIT repository without prompt password, now I've installed GIT in windows using `MobaXterm` software to emulate unix machine.

What I want to do is to set up this new machine to have ssh-auth without prompting password, How could I do this with the existing ssh-keys that I have in my VM?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try to copy ssh file from ubuntu to window. It can be found in .ssh folder inside users home directory. check using command ls -l $HOME/.ssh. copy  this file to .ssh folder inside users home directory